# Mac mini 2018 hdmi white noise

Tags: display, mojave, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have 2018 mac mini, just bought it a few days ago, running OS X Mojave. And I have 2 monitors connected to it, 1 through usb-c and 1 through HDMI.

Whenever I wake my computer up from sleep, the monitor connected through usb-c wakes up instantly, but the other one takes a while to wake up. Like I could already be using the left screen and the right one is still black.

I tried plugging a different display to this HDMI port and it's the same story, the monitor takes like 1 minute to start displaying the picture, after I wake my computer from sleep, but, this other monitor instead of just being a black screen displays white noise and then wakes up.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You should check whether the update to 10.14.6 has fixed the issue for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Well, I don't really care anymore, because I bought a new monitor. Is there something they fixed?

Comment: There are two fixed listed that may be relevant: a graphics issue when waking from sleep, and an issue of a black screen specifically on the Mini. My monitor seems to be behaving itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of reports of monitor problems with the 2018 Mini: so many that it seems unlikely to be anything other than a problem with the hardware itself (or specific firmware/software to that model).

I myself see the same problem: white noise on the HDMI-connected monitor after Sleep.

Using 2 TB/USB-c ports rather than one TB/USB-C and one HDMI may be a factor, rather than the cable itself.

It's unknown at this stage whether Apple may be able to fix it (with enough bug reports) in a software update, or whether it's a permanent hardware issue.

Comment: I do have the [exact same issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378615/mac-mini-2018-hdmi-issue-with-23-apple-cinema-display). It looks like a HDMI issue or HDMI adatper incompatibility. Which HDMI adapters are fully supported? The HMDI connection has been the main reason why I have purchased the Mac mini.

Comment: @howdytom I'm connecting the HDMI port to an HDMI display with a standard HDMI cable: no adapters involved. Since <some Mojave update> things have improved: I no longer get static on wake from sleep, but both displays take up to about 20 seconds to fully wake up, blinking and going dark several times in the process.